# query to show one column names in comma seperated list

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am working in mysql database and i need some help in listing down one column data values to be shown as comma separated, Actually there are two tables: one is persons table and the other one is groups table, now one person can belong to many groups, so i am trying to show the users data.

I want to show the data like this:

```
UserName                 Group            Email
User #1                  Grp1,Grp3,Grp5   user1@email.com
User #2                  Grp3,Grp1        user2@email.com
```

This is my query

```
select ft_smsender_groups as g left join (select p1.id,p2.group_id 
from ft_smsender_persons2groups as p2 inner join ft_smsender_persons 
as p1 on p1.id = p2.person_id ) as p2 on g.id = p2.group_id','g.id,g.name,
created,updated where 
deleted = 0 group by id,name
```

There are actually three tables involved:

```
ft_smsender_groups
ft_smsender_persons2groups - This table holds key from both the tables
ft_smsender_persons
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL : multiple column values as 1 comma-separated string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589203/mysql-multiple-column-values-as-1-comma-separated-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT   p.name, p.email, GROUP_CONCAT(g.name) AS groups
FROM     ft_smsender_persons AS p
JOIN     ft_smsender_persons2groups AS p2g ON p.id = p2g.person_id 
JOIN     ft_smsender_groups AS g ON g.id = p2g.group_id
WHERE    deleted = 0
GROUP BY p.name, p.email
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `GROUP_COUNCAT(your_filed_name)` function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat